# LINQ Many-to-Many on complex nested identifiers

Tags: c#, linq

I'm sure this has been answered, but for the life of me I can't find it.

I have three entities:

```
class Customer
{
  string id;
  List<Vendor> vendors;
}

class Vendor
{
  string id;
}

class Distributor
{
  string id;
  List<Vendor> vendors;
  List<Customer> customers;
}
```

The problem comes when the only Repo method I have gets all Customers from the database for a Distributor. This means the Distributors collection has not only the Vendors they represent, but all vendors working with that customer.

What I need to do is filter the `Customer.Vendors` list down to just the vendors that match any ID in the `Distributor.Vendors` list.

Something like the following:

```
Customer.Vendors = Customer.Vendors
  .Where(v => v.id *any matches to Distributor.Vendors.Any.id*).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

For EF query you can try selecting ids from `Distributor` and using `Contains` on resulting collection:

```
Distributor d = ....;
Customer.Vendors = dbContext.Vendors
  .Where(v => d.Vendors.Select(dv => dv.Id).Contains(v.Id))
  .ToList();
```

If it is LINQ to objects it is better to move the ids collection to materialized collection(or even `HashSet`) in separate variable:

```
var distributorIds = d.Vendors.Select(dv => dv.Id).ToList();
Customer.Vendors = Customer.Vendors
  .Where(v => distributorIds.Contains(v.Id))
  .ToList();
```

Or `.Where(v => Distributor.Vendors.Any(dv => dv.Id == v.Id))`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.Any()` would be an easy solution. *No benchmarks were made..*

Assuming you have a `Customer` object `c` and a `Distributor` object `d`

```
c.Vendors = c.Vendors
  .Where(v => d.Vendors.Any(cv => cv.Id == v.Id)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
var distribVendorIds = Distributors.Vendors.Select(v=>v.id);

Customer.Vendors = Customer.Vendors
  .Where(v => distribVendorIds.Any(t => t ==v.id)).ToList();
```

Comment: `.Any()` take a Func like a parameter or without any parameter. i think this will not compile. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: This is what happens when you answer a post on a iPhone! I’ve edited my answer